# How can I import a C++ python extension into a module in another directory?

Tags: python, import, module

Here is the directory structure:

```
app/
    __init__.py
    sub1/
        __init__.py
        mod1.py
    sub2/
        __init__.py
        sub2.so
        test_sub2.py
```

- The folder app is on my PYTHONPATH
- All of the __init__.py files are empty.
- The shared library sub2.so is a C++ extension module that I compiled using cmake and boost-python.
- test_sub2.py is a test script for the class defined in sub2.so.
- If I run test_sub2.py from the sub2 directory, it imports the module correctly and the test passes.

How do I import the class A from sub2.so into mod1.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to import it is to import `app.sub2.sub2`, from any source file. Your test should actually live outside of `app` and use that module-path to get to the extension module.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import .app.sub2.sub2
```

in your mod1.py file

Answer (score 0):

Use relative imports:

```
from ..sub2.sub2 import A
```

This is similar to a relative path "../sub2/sub2.so".